# What are the available ethereum/erc20 standard wallet on China's appstore?

Tags: erc-20, wallets

Heard that ImToken wallet is removed from Chinese appstore ; Am looking for a ethereum based wallet that could be downloaded from the Chinese appstore.

Comment: Check Trust, Status.im, Gnosis Safe